# Xcode setdelegate:self error message

Tags: xcode

Hi i have some code which parses xml data from a web server .  I had it running in 4.2 for ages and it all worked fine however when i updated to IOS5 and ran on an iphone 4 this particular lien in my code started giving me an error when it didnt before

```
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
```

The error being cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id < NSXMLParserDelegate >    ' with an Ivalue of type my_function.

A) i dont really know what this means so could anyone explain?
B) How come it worked for 4.2 and its only giving an error on IOS5

Thanks

Comment: Are you implementing the NSXMLParserDelegate protocol?  Does it actually say my_function or did you edit that?  In either case, does "my_function" exist?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue in which code was working in 3.6 release of xcode but not in xcode 4.4.1.
And fix is to explicitly declare the protocol in interface declaration (in C++ terms, explicitly declare that class referenced by 'self' is implementing the interface)

Something like:

```
@interface my_function : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate, BlahBlahDelegate>  {
```

I think older compilers did not complain about this.